# Is there any free cricket game in ubuntu 20

Tags: software-recommendation, games

I was searching for cricket but could not find any, there were some but those required a few hacks.
Is there any free game of cricket designed for ubuntu?

Comment: Are you sure you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as it's intended as a *headless* system (ie. no GUI) for appliances, devices or cloud use.  Games are usually played on desktop systems like Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which can use *deb* packages (releases using the *year* format are *snap* package only server products).

Comment: Site rules do not allow the making of software recommendations.

Comment: @David: Where did you see that rule? Ubuntu help states that questions about **Running third-party applications on Ubuntu** are okay: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic